I need to curve the white space with CSS without losing the dimensions
I need help with this I need to have a result like this on the way
This is the way
This is the HTML code


.parte__roja-camino {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  display:flex;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.parte__roja-camino > div {
  width: calc(100% / 13);
  height: 100%;
}

.parte__roja-7{
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  background: red;
}
 <div class="parte__roja-camino">
    <div class="parte__roja-1">1</div>
    <div class="parte__roja-2">2</div>
    <div class="parte__roja-3">3</div>
    <div class="parte__roja-seguro">
      <span class="parte-salida">salida</span>
    </div>
    <div class="parte__roja-5">5</div>
    <div class="parte__roja-6">6</div>
    <div class="parte__roja-7">7</div>
    <div class="parte__roja-8">8</div>
    <div class="parte__roja-9">9</div>
    <div class="parte__roja-seguro">seguro</div>
    <div class="parte__roja-11">11</div>
    <div class="parte__roja-12">12</div>
    <div class="parte__roja-13">13</div>
 </div>

// And this is the css 



The result should look like this
[result]
This is how the code is going. I need help to curve in the white space of the red block that covers that red space. The height should be 20% and the width 100%.
This is how the project goes
